# Excel file opens file on second double click only

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-excel-2016

When I double click an XLSX file in Explorer, Excel starts, but does not open the file.
When I double click the same file again while Excel is already open, the file is opened.
However, if I close Excel in between, it starts empty again.

This is Excel from Office Professional Plus 2016, Version 2105 (Build 14026.20308; 16.0.14026.20294 when I click on the Info button). My PC is a quite fresh installation, about 2 weeks old.

I have checked:

- The Registry entry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx` points to `Excel.Sheet.12`.
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command` points to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /dde`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\ddeexec` is `[open("%1" /ou "%u")]`

I don't see what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you backup the entry "command" first.

Then please try to add "%1" in "(Default)" data value to check this issue.

[image]